# multi step form using keyup function for form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a multi step form. I add a validation on each step using jquery. If fields are empty then next button is disabled. If fields are not empty next button is enabled.

I used this code for validation

```
$('form.webform-client-form').bind("change keyup",function(){
var card_name = $('#edit-submitted-first-name1').val();
var card_number = $('#edit-submitted-card-number').val();
var expiration_year = $('#edit-submitted-expiration-year-year').val();
var expiration_month = $('#edit-submitted-expiration-year-month').val();
var cvv = $('#edit-submitted-cvv').val();
if (card_name != "" && card_number != "" && expiration_year != "" && expiration_month !="" && cvv != ""){
  $('form.webform-client-form').find('#edit-submit').attr('disabled', false);
  $('form.webform-client-form').find('#edit-submit').addClass('active');
}
else {
$('form.webform-client-form').find('#edit-submit').attr('disabled', true);
  $('form.webform-client-form').find('#edit-submit').removeClass('active');
}
});
```

The problem is that when user fill the information in the form he clicks the next button and if he click to prev button and he back to first form all the information are prefilled but next button is not enabled until user enter some value because of keyup function. I want next button is enabled if user back to prev form.

Is there any way to resolve this problem or there is any other approach for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First move all the logic from the binding in a different function, then call that in the binding, and when pressing the back button call the validation function you used for key-up. That way it will check for the fields and enable the button

Answer (score 0):

You need to decouple your enabling and disabling of the next button from the key up being the only event that calls it.  I would move it out to a common function which is called when there is a relevant keyup and a value next button click from the previous step.